# How to keep a custom canvas image "cursor" close to the "mouse/touch" on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a canvas draw feature for a small note app.

The particularity of this screen is that there is a "cursor", say, in the form of a pencil or eraser to carry out its respective function.

**The problem is that the line is constantly far away from the "cursor". And I am not able to resolve even using Chatgpt.**

This is the application Pen?
Codepen:
https://codepen.io/rafaeldcastro/pen/GRYVzdj?editors=1010

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
    <img id="drawing-indicator" width="50" height="50" src=https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/266/266146.png style="display:none">
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    <button id="pencil">Pencil</button>
    <button id="eraser">Eraser</button>
    <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
const clear = document.querySelector("#clear");
const pencil = document.querySelector("#pencil");
const eraser = document.querySelector("#eraser");
const canvas = document.getElementById("drawing-board");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const drawingIndicator = document.querySelector("#drawing-indicator");

const canvasOffsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
const canvasOffsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;

let selectedTool = "pencil";
const pencilImage = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/266/266146.png";
const eraserImage =
    "https://creazilla-store.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/cliparts/33173/eraser-clipart-md.png";
let isPainting = false;
let lineWidth = 5;
let startX;
let startY;

let isDrawingIndicatorVisible = false;
let drawingIndicatorX;
let drawingIndicatorY;

clear.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

pencil.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    selectedTool = "pencil";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    lineWidth = 5;
    drawingIndicator.src = pencilImage;
    drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
});

eraser.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    selectedTool = "eraser";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
    lineWidth = 25;
    drawingIndicator.src = eraserImage;
    drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
});

const startDrawing = (x, y) => {
    isPainting = true;
    startX = x;
    startY = y;

    if (selectedTool === "pencil") {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x - canvasOffsetX, y - canvasOffsetY);
    } else if (selectedTool === "eraser") {
        ctx.clearRect(
            x - canvasOffsetX - lineWidth / 2,
            y - canvasOffsetY - lineWidth / 2,
            lineWidth,
            lineWidth
        );
    }

    updateDrawingIndicator(x, y);
};

const stopDrawing = () => {
    isPainting = false;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
};

const draw = (x, y) => {
    if (!isPainting) {
        return;
    }

    if (selectedTool === "pencil") {
        ctx.lineTo(x - canvasOffsetX, y - canvasOffsetY);
        ctx.stroke();
    } else if (selectedTool === "eraser") {
        ctx.clearRect(
            x - canvasOffsetX - lineWidth / 2,
            y - canvasOffsetY - lineWidth / 2,
            lineWidth,
            lineWidth
        );
    }
};

const updateDrawingIndicator = (x, y) => {
    const offsetX = drawingIndicator.width / 2;
    const offsetY = drawingIndicator.height / 2;
    drawingIndicatorX = x - offsetX;
    drawingIndicatorY = y - offsetY;
    drawingIndicator.style.left = drawingIndicatorX + "px";
    drawingIndicator.style.top = drawingIndicatorY + "px";
};

const getCursorPosition = (event) => {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width;
    const scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;
    const x = (event.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX;
    const y = (event.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY;
    return { x, y };
};

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    if (!isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e);
        startDrawing(x, y);

        isDrawingIndicatorVisible = true;
        drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        stopDrawing();

        isDrawingIndicatorVisible = false;
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e);
        draw(x, y);
        updateDrawingIndicator(x, y);
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
    if (!isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e.touches[0]);
        startDrawing(x, y);

        isDrawingIndicatorVisible = true;
        drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        stopDrawing();
        if (isDrawingIndicatorVisible) {
            isDrawingIndicatorVisible = false;
        }
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e.touches[0]);
        draw(x, y);
        updateDrawingIndicator(x, y);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `startDrawing()` and `draw()`, the coordinate (x,y) is already correct, just remove `- canvasOffsetX` and `- canvasOffsetY`. That would make the line appear right at the mouse cursor. The tools' cursor position will depend on the icon used. In the following code I have fixed the pencil, but the eraser look weird. You can try finding other icon or add some more code to determinate the position for each icon.

```js
const clear = document.querySelector("#clear");
const pencil = document.querySelector("#pencil");
const eraser = document.querySelector("#eraser");
const canvas = document.getElementById("drawing-board");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const drawingIndicator = document.querySelector("#drawing-indicator");

const canvasOffsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
const canvasOffsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;

let selectedTool = "pencil";
const pencilImage = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/266/266146.png";
const eraserImage =
    "https://creazilla-store.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/cliparts/33173/eraser-clipart-md.png";
let isPainting = false;
let lineWidth = 5;
let startX;
let startY;

let isDrawingIndicatorVisible = false;
let drawingIndicatorX;
let drawingIndicatorY;

clear.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

pencil.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    selectedTool = "pencil";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    lineWidth = 5;
    drawingIndicator.src = pencilImage;
    drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
});

eraser.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    selectedTool = "eraser";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
    lineWidth = 25;
    drawingIndicator.src = eraserImage;
    drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
});

const startDrawing = (x, y) => {
    isPainting = true;
    startX = x;
    startY = y;

    if (selectedTool === "pencil") {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x , y );
    } else if (selectedTool === "eraser") {
        ctx.clearRect(
            x - lineWidth / 2,
            y - lineWidth / 2,
            lineWidth,
            lineWidth
        );
    }

    updateDrawingIndicator(x, y);
};

const stopDrawing = () => {
    isPainting = false;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
};

const draw = (x, y) => {
    if (!isPainting) {
        return;
    }

    if (selectedTool === "pencil") {
        ctx.lineTo(x , y );
        ctx.stroke();
    } else if (selectedTool === "eraser") {
        ctx.clearRect(
            x  - lineWidth / 2,
            y - lineWidth / 2,
            lineWidth,
            lineWidth
        );
    }
};

const updateDrawingIndicator = (x, y) => {
    //const offsetX = drawingIndicator.width / 2;
    //const offsetY = drawingIndicator.height / 2;
    drawingIndicatorX = x + canvas.offsetLeft;
    drawingIndicatorY = y + canvas.offsetTop - drawingIndicator.height;
    drawingIndicator.style.left = drawingIndicatorX + "px";
    drawingIndicator.style.top = drawingIndicatorY + "px";
};

const getCursorPosition = (event) => {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width;
    const scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;
    const x = (event.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX;
    const y = (event.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY;
    return { x, y };
};

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    if (!isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e);
        startDrawing(x, y);

        isDrawingIndicatorVisible = true;
        drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        stopDrawing();

        isDrawingIndicatorVisible = false;
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e);
        draw(x, y);
        updateDrawingIndicator(x, y);
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
    if (!isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e.touches[0]);
        startDrawing(x, y);

        isDrawingIndicatorVisible = true;
        drawingIndicator.style.display = "block";
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        stopDrawing();
        if (isDrawingIndicatorVisible) {
            isDrawingIndicatorVisible = false;
        }
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
    if (isPainting) {
        const { x, y } = getCursorPosition(e.touches[0]);
        draw(x, y);
        updateDrawingIndicator(x, y);
    }
});
```

```css
#drawing-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  display:none
}

canvas {
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <img id="drawing-indicator" width="50" height="50" src=https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/266/266146.png>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    <button id="pencil">Pencil</button>
    <button id="eraser">Eraser</button>
    <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
</section>
```